# Adding custom button right of Forward in outlook

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook-addin, addin-express

In Outlook 2013's reading pane, we got the new quick REPLY, REPLY ALL and FORWARD. Is it possible to to add a custom button next to "FORWARD" (indicated by the red arrow here) using AddinExprees https://www.add-in-express.com ?
[image]

Comment: No, you cannot do that.